# Cross product and Jacobian

Tags: chain-rule

[image]
How does one obtain the Eq(1)? Why is there a cross product on the right side?

Comment: Because there is a cross-product on the left?

Comment: "Why is there a cross product in the right-hand side"? Short answer: because there is one in the left-hand side, too. It's just some vector calculus, nothing deep.

Comment: But how does one derive that? That’s where I’m struggling.

Comment: Write out the cross-product as a determinant:   $\vec a\times \vec b=\begin{vmatrix} i&j&k\\a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\end{vmatrix}$.

Comment: No, don't write it as a determinant! Just multiply out the brackets. Something like in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884982/factorizing-a-cross-product

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward using $a\times a=0, a\times b=-b\times a$  together with $(a+b)\times c=a\times c+b\times c$.  And of course $ra\times b=r(a\times b)$.